# Hello world using AJAX and SPRING not working

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying make hello world using ajax and spring, but it not workit, I dont know why.

My servlet is:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String processAJAXRequest(
            @RequestParam("firstname") String firstname,
            @RequestParam("lastname") String lastname) {
        String response = "HELLO: " + firstname + " " + lastname;
        return response;
    }
}
```

And my page with ajax is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1250">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="sampleForm" method="post" action="/profile">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#sampleForm').submit(
                        function (event) {
                            var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
                            var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
                            var data = 'firstname='
                                    + encodeURIComponent(firstname)
                                    + '&lastname='
                                    + encodeURIComponent(lastname);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: $("#sampleForm").attr("action"),
                                data: data,
                                type: "GET",
                                success: function (response) {
                                    alert(response);
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try to send form, I am getting `error 404`. Can you help me? Where is a problem?

Normal servlet `extends` from `HttpServlet` working fine.

Comment: What is your dispatcher servlet path?

Comment: I think it is /profile

Comment: If it is /profile, the dispatcher servlet in web.xml, then the url path would be /profile/profile.

Comment: My normal servlets are on localhost:8080 its not be /profile. I havent any configuration in web xml, I am using @WebServlet("/login") for set a dispatch.

Comment: See in the net panel what URL are you calling with the Ajax call. Also try it by hand it the browser http://localhost:8080/profile?firstname=Jhon&lastname=Dohn or http://localhost:8080/profile/profile?firstname=Jhon&lastname=Dohn  or whatever.